# Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, arm, raspberrypi

I was reading info on this [Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi). It says...

> With the release of the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and its ARMv7-based
>   BCM2709 processor, it is now possible to run Ubuntu directly on the
>   Raspberry Pi.
>
> Note that the information on this page currently only applies to the
>   Raspberry Pi 2 and 3, not the original Raspberry Pi. The Raspberry Pi
>   3 does not (yet) work with official Ubuntu images out of the box, but
>   unofficial images are available.

That page is stamped

> last edited 2016-08-09 13:18:45 by ssweeny

But the [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/arm) says

> Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS includes support for the very latest ARM-based
>   server systems powered by certified 64-bit processors

I know there is an "Ubuntu MATE" OS that works on a Raspberry Pi, but I would rather use official Ubuntu images since they offer long term support. In the quote above, they reference an "ARMv7" but I just bought a Raspberry Pi 3 and it is a "64-bit quad-core ARMv8 CPU", which sounds like the official Ubuntu images should work.

My question is, does Ubuntu's latest download work on a Raspberry Pi 3 with a "64-bit quad-core ARMv8 CPU"?

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.1/release/ shows there is an ISO for 64-bit ARMv8 processors and above. I don't own a Raspberry Pi 3, so I can't test if it works, so try this at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, but it's only a 32bit build.  It does not take advantage of 64bit architecture.  It's like downloading i686 build and running on x86_64 hardware.